# Can an Indian citizen with a US green card travel to Colombia without a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, colombia, us-permanent-residents

Can an Indian citizen with a US green card travel to Colombia without a visa as a tourist for 10 days?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, travel without a visa is allowed. According to [the Colombian government's "do I need a visa" page](https://www.cancilleria.gov.co/en/procedures_services/visa/requirements), Indian citizens traveling for tourism

> do not need a visa to enter Colombia if you are a US or Schengen visa holder with a minimum validity of 180 days at the time of entering Colombia (an airport transit visa is not admissible) or you have residence permit in a Member State of the Schengen Area or in the United States of America.

Do note that all visitors to Colombia at this time must follow the [covid-19 safety rules](https://colombia.travel/en/covid-19-information), including filling out the online [check-mig form](https://www.migracioncolombia.gov.co/check-mig) 24 hours before traveling.

Comment: They're also still [mandating masks outdoors](https://www.travelawaits.com/2701203/things-to-know-before-visiting-colombia/) which would be difficult during their summer. I'd consider visiting a destination with more relaxed rules and higher vaccination rates.